# Deduction about ideals of same norm being identical

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-14})$, trying to factor the ideal $\langle 2 + \sqrt{-14} \rangle$ one gets that it can be written as the product $\mathfrak{c}\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{q}$, where
$\mathfrak{p} = \langle 2, \sqrt{-14} \rangle$ and $\mathfrak{q} = \langle 3, 1 + \sqrt{-14} \rangle$ which have norm $2$ and $3$ respectively. By taking the norm on both sides of the factorisation one deduces that the norm of $\mathfrak{c}$ is 3. At this point my notes deduce from this that $\mathfrak{c}$ must be either $\mathfrak{q}$ or $\mathfrak{q}' = \langle 3, 1-\sqrt{-14} \rangle$ which also has norm 3. My question is: how are we sure that it must coincide with one of these two? Do you by any chance know that $\mathfrak{q}$, $\mathfrak{q}'$ are the *only* norm 3 prime ideals?

Comment: In $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]$, not the same as its fraction field. Prime ideals are maximal in such rings of integers. $(3)$ is a product of two maximal ideals, there can't be any other maximal ideal containing $3$.

Comment: The way you've written it, $q'$ is $q$. Maybe you wanted $1-\sqrt{-14}$?

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks